# Can't get cron job to run on Google App Engine Flexible Environment (Python)

Tags: python, cron

I have tried to get a cron job running in Google App Engine Flexible Environment in Python, but I couldn't get it to work. My app.yaml and cron.yaml are from the documents and posted below. For some reason, even the simplest functions I write are not working when I try to run the cron job. Does this have to do with how my app.yaml is set up? This is strange because cron jobs I used to have like this in the Standard Environment of GAE used to work fine. Once I switched to the Flexible Environment, the cron jobs stopped working.

**main.py**

```
@app.route('/printhi/')
def printhi():
    print("hi")
    return "Printed Hi"
```

**cron.yaml**

```
cron:
- description: "Print Hi"
  url: /printhi
  schedule: every day 08:00
  timezone: America/Los_Angeles
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

manual_scaling:
  instances: 2
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 3
  disk_size_gb: 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late, but have you set up your App Engine's firewall?

IP addresses 0.1.0.2 and 10.0.0.1 need to be allowed in order to [validate Cron requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#validating_cron_requests)
.